# Getting data object in button's (located in ListView row) listener

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

Okay, title is propably unclear, here is what i want to do:
I have ListView and inside each row there is some text and a button. I'm setting listener to each button (in my custom list Adapter) like that:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li;
        li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    Item elem = elems.get(position);
    TextView mainText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main_text);
    TextView sideText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.side_text);

    mainText.setText(elem.desc);
    sideText.setText(timestampToString(elem.date));

    Button againButton = (Button) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.itemAgainButton);

    againButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // onClick actions
        }
    });
```

Now inside onClick method i need to acces Item object from which current row was created. I'm not sure if it's clear what i want to do. Here i'm setting listener on ListView elements in my Activity class

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Item item = (Item) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    DidItItemActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", item.id);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

and I can use `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` which gives me exactly what i need. How can i do the same in Adapter class?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all you should initialize LayoutInflater in getView method. Much better place to do this is adapter's constructor. Cause constructor is called only once, and getView method will be called many times.

And now let's go to your main issue. You shouldn't call onClick method in adapter class, but in activity. To do this you can make use of setting tag for given view. To implement this you first need to declare a class inside your adapter class

```
public static class ViewHolder {
     int mId;
}
```

Then you have to set appropriate id to each tag, which will be bind with view.
Like this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {
    ...
    ViewHolder tag = new ViewHolder();
    convertView.setTag(tag);
}

Item elem = elems.get(position);
...

ViewHolder tag = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
tag.mId = elem.id;
...
}
```

Last part is about getting id value in onClick method. When onClick is called you simply need to call getTag method on given view:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                ViewHolder tag = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                int id = tag.mId;
                }
```

And the last thing, setting onClickListener is better to do in newView method.